# CiviMail token for sender signature

Tags: civimail, tokens

Is there a token for email **sender's** signature?

I need the email generated from template to be signed by the person who is sending the email.

Comment: I'd like to add user's signature after each template in case we send a mailing/bulk emails.
Any news about that ? The best would be to get a token user_signature
Best regards,
Fabien

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is but it only works for regular mails not for mails sent by CiviMail (bulk mails):

1. Add signature to the CIviCRM contact that is connected to your CMS contact (see screenshot).
2. Click on send email for a contact and the signatures should be in the Text editor.

However, for Bulk Mails you would have to put the signature in a footer or th emessage template.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This way CiviCRM is adding the signature of Recipient, not the Sender.

Comment: You are right, the token indeed resolves the recipient's signature. However, If add a signature to the CiviCRM contact that is connected to my CMS user, the signature will be displayed as soon as I pull up the send email mask. Just tested it again and it works for me using CiviCRM 4.7.17 and Drupal.

Comment: That's correct. But how can I use such a signature together with email template?

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible. You can of course cut out the signature and paste it again after selecting the template or implement custom token/functions, javascript magic etc...

Comment: I couldn't get this to work properly, but there is an extension de.systopia.signatures (https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.signatures) which has the functionality needed.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the code in https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.sigs a useful starting place for a token for CiviMail - a PR for this would be welcome. Feel free to contact me if you would like us to develop it for you.